# jQuery and selecting a select list item

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery and am having a problem selecting an item in a select list. I have implemented cascading select boxes as show in this [post](http://jsatt.blogspot.com/2010/01/cascading-select-boxes-using-jquery.html). Everything is working fine except for setting a default.

The problem is that I need to select one of the child items when the page is first loaded.

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function cascadeSelect(parent, child, childVal) {
        var childOptions = child.find('option:not(.static)');
        child.data('options', childOptions);

        parent.change(function () {
            childOptions.remove();
            child
                    .append(child.data('options').filter('.sub_' + this.value))
                    .change();
        })

        childOptions.not('.static, .sub_' + parent.val()).remove();

        if (childVal != '') {
            child.find("option[value=" + childVal + "]").attr("selected", "selected");
        }
    }

    $(function () {
        cascadeForm = $('.cascadeTest');
        parentSelect = cascadeForm.find('.parent');
        childSelect = cascadeForm.find('.child');

        cascadeSelect(parentSelect, childSelect, "5");
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<select class='parent' name='parent' size='10'>
  <option value='1'>Category 1 -></option>
  <option value='2'>Category 2 -></option>
</select>
<select class='child' id='child' size='10'>
  <option class='sub_1' value='5'>Custom Subcategory 1.1</option>
  <option class='sub_1' value='3'>Subcategory 1.1</option>
  <option class='sub_2' value='4'>Subcategory 2.1</option>
</select>
```

The second select list should show up inside the right box but it does not.

[image]

The child.find call is being hit but does not select the item.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you post the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

The problem with your code is that you remove every single "child" option form the DOM!

```
childOptions.not('.static, .sub_' + parent.val()).remove();
```

In your html there are not childOptions with `static` as a class, so the above removes all existing `childOptions`. This is why you see nothing on the right.

Otherwise, it's a little unclear what you're trying to do with `.data()` but the default selection works if you remove that line:

### **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/DQrmU/)**

```
function cascadeSelect(parent, child, childVal) {

    var childOptions = child.find('option:not(.static)');
    child.data('options', childOptions);

    parent.change(function () {
        childOptions.remove();
        child.append(child.data('options').filter('.sub_' + this.value)).change();
    })


    // This like removes all the option!
    // childOptions.not('.static, .sub_' + parent.val()).remove();

    if (childVal != '') {
        child.find("option[value=" + childVal + "]").attr("selected", "selected");
    }
}

$(function () {
    cascadeForm = $('.cascadeTest');
    parentSelect = cascadeForm.find('.parent');
    childSelect = cascadeForm.find('.child');

    cascadeSelect(parentSelect, childSelect, "5");
});
```

​

---

**[`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)** will look in the descendants, maybe you want to **[`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** the selected elements?:

Also, I often have better luck using `.attr("selected", true)` and `false` to deselect.

```
    if (childVal != '') {
        child.filter("option[value=" + childVal + "]").attr("selected", true);
    }
```

**[Here is a jsFiddle example that sets the default value of an options list.](http://jsfiddle.net/ckF4A/)**

Comment: I changed the line to match yours but still no go. I also verified that the code is being hit. Perhaps the real issue is that I need to do something else to make the second select list display instead of remain hidden? I'll update my question with an image.

Comment: @rboarman - You were removing all the child `option` s from the DOM - edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're only setting the value for the child list which at the page startup isn't visible because nothing in the parent list is selected yet. Try something like this in your document .ready():

```
parentSelect.val("1").change();
childSelect.val("5");
```

[jsfiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/gZ8B4/)

Comment: Your answer in combination with Peter's got me past this issue onto the next one. :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(selectList).val(value);
```

That's it. you don't have a checked attribute but a value

Comment: You mean like this? $('.cascadeTest').find('.child').val(childVal); It doesn't seem to be doing anything.